# Performance of looping over array of dicts in Julia

Tags: julia

I am doing loops over arrays/vector of dicts. My Julia performance is slower than Python.
Run time is 25% longer than Python.

The toy program below represents the structure of what I am doing.

```
const poems = [
    Dict(
        :text => "Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary, Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—",
        :author => "Edgar Allen Poe"),
    Dict(
        :text => "Because I could not stop for Death – He kindly stopped for me – The Carriage held but just Ourselves – And Immortality.",
        :author => "Emily Dickinson"),
    # etc... 10,000 more    
]

const remove_count = [
    Dict(:words => "the", :count => 0),
    Dict(:words => "and", :count => 0),
    # etc... 100 more
]

function loop_poems(poems, remove_count)
    for p in poems
        for r in remove_count
            if occursin(r[:words], p[:text])
                r[:count] += 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

How do I optimize?  I have read through Performance Tips in Julia website:

First, I declare constants.

Second, I assume since I pass arguments `remove count` and `poems` into the function, I don't need to declare as `global`.

Third, the meat of the processing (the loops) are in a function.

Fourth... I don't know how to declare types in an array of dicts (specifically for performance).  How to do it?  Would it help performance?

Comment: If a poem includes two copies of a counted word, like `poem[1]` has two occurances of `"and"`, does it count as +1 or +2 to the count?

Comment: And what about case-sensitivity? The `"The"` in `poem[2]` is counted as a `"the"` occurance?

Comment: In my real program, I downcase everything and remove puncuation in "pre-processing".  In this toy example, not worried about accuracy, but am wondering why my peformance is slower than Python.  I wasn't expecting Julia to be same speed or slower than Python.

Comment: Why is `remove_count` a vector of dictionary and not one dictionary? (this has a performance cost as well)

Comment: yes, what are you trying to do? Your example looks odd, one would have expected the poems to be a vector of named tuples (or directly `Poem` structure) and `remove_count` a dictionary stint/integer..

Comment: I'm using mostly importing tabular data, so you're seeing each row in table as an element of any array.  Sure I could use different structure, but as written and as a comparison to same structure between python, I was wondering if there anything I could be doing in Julia to make it faster.

Comment: Intuitively, the double loop in `loop_poems` is not very efficient. But this would stand out (and be comparable to other methods) with larger inputs (as you say you have). So, it would be very helpful to get a more comprehensive test problem i.e. are poems longer? more `remove_word` examples,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here seems to be, what we call "type instability". Julia code is fast, when Julia can figure out the correct types at runtime, but is slower when the types are not known. To figure out, if there is any kind of type instability, you can use the `@code_warntype` macro in your REPL:

```
julia> @code_warntype loop_poems(poems, remove_count)
```

StackOverflow does not show the colors of the output, but you should look out for red parts, that indicate that Julia cannot narrow down the types enough. Yellow parts also indicate places, where the type is not known exactly, but these parts are often intentionally, so we have to worry less about them.

In my case (Julia v1.8.5) the following lines have some red color

```
│   %17 = Base.getindex(r, :words)::Any
│   %18 = Base.getindex(p, :text)::String
│   %19 = Main.occursin(%17, %18)::Bool
└──       goto #5 if not %19
4 ─ %21 = Base.getindex(r, :count)::Any
│   %22 = (%21 + 1)::Any
```

the suffixes `::Any` indicate that Julia could only infer the type `Any` here, which could be any type.

We also see that this happens in the cases of `Base.getindex(r, :words)` and `Base.getindex(r, :count)` - these are  just the de-sugared expressions `r[:words]` and `r[:count]`.

So why is that the case? If we look at the type of `remove_count` with

```
julia> typeof(remove_count)
Vector{Dict{Symbol, Any}}
```

We see that that the key type of the dictionary can only be a `Symbol` - but the value type can be any kind of type. We can get a very moderate speed up by constructing `remove_count` so that we narrow down the value type to a union:

```
const remove_count = Dict{Symbol, Union{String, Int}[
    Dict(:words => "the", :count => 0),
    Dict(:words => "and", :count => 0),
    # etc... 100 more
]
```

Running `@code_warntype` again, shows, that we still have some red entries, but this time at least they are of type `Union{String, Int}` - but the speed up is still disappointing.

As others have pointed out, it might be better, if you find a different data structure so that your code is type stable.

There are multiple ways to do that. Probably the easiest is to use a vector of `NamedTuple`:

```
const remove_count = [
    (word="the", count=0),
    (word="and", count=0),
    # etc... 100 more
)
```

so that

```
typeof(remove_count)
Vector{NamedTuple{(:word, :count), Tuple{String, Int64}}}
```

and your function then becomes

```
function loop_poems(poems, remove_count)
    for p in poems
        for i in eachindex(remove_count)
            word = remove_count[i].word
            count = remove_count[i].count
            if occursin(word, text)
                # NamedTuple is immutable, so wee need to create a new one
                remove_count[i] = (word=word, count=count + 1)     
            end
        end
    end
end
```

If we use `@code_warntype` again, the red parts have disappeared.

There are few other easy improvements:

- Use the `@inbounds` macro when looping over arrays: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/boundscheck/#Eliding-bounds-checks
- Move `p[:text]` into the outer loop

and your function then becomes:

```
function loop_poems(poems, remove_count)
    @inbounds for p in poems
        text = p[:text]
        for i in eachindex(remove_count)
            word = remove_count[i].word
            count = remove_count[i].count
            if occursin(word, text)
                # NamedTuple is immutable, so wee need to create a new one
                remove_count[i] = (word=word, count=count + 1)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

It also might make sense to also convert `poems` into a vector of `NamedTuple`.

Ultimately, if you still need more performance, you might better look at your domain and at more complex string algorithms:

- Can your words contain any white spaces? If not, maybe split the poems into tokens.
- If you have a lot of words, your words might share a lot of prefixes - in such a case a trie might be of help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Thank you very much for showing how to troubleshoot/optimize.  This answer is useful not only for this question, but for all of my scripts going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You want `function loop_poems(poems, remove_count)`, not `function loop_poems(poem, remove_count)`. Your code as written is accessing `poems` as a global variable.

Comment: @FeFiFoFu How are you profiling? Are you running it as a script?

Comment: @HarmonicaMuse: Yes I am running it as a script. With my production data, it takes 5 hours to run due size of data. That is including the use of Threads.